# Button not fitting its text

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout` with two buttons. But, when a button has some longer text that needs breaking, the button's height does not expand to fit the text. Instead it crops the text.

Here's what I have:

```
<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/previous_button"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/next_button"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help on why button crops the text?

[image: Here's a screenshot of the layout]

Comment: if the orientation is horizental and has given some weight then add width as "0"

Comment: Make your button width 0 dp

Comment: add a new line (\n) in your <string>

Comment: 0dp did not do the trick. Still crops the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:singleLine="false"` property to the problematic button. Hope this solve your problem.

If it doesn't work, probably you'll need to remove the button's default padding by adding `android:padding="0dp"`

Comment: @HelderMPinhal Have you tried this possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the text to align in multi-lines.
A horizontal LinearLayout aligns the baselines of all its child controls by default. So the first line of text in your multi-line button is vertically aligned with the single line of text in the other buttons.

To disable this behaviour, set android:baselineAligned="false" on the LinearLayout

For Example,

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two_board_btn_continue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue_button"
                android:text="@string/continue_bidding"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two_board_btn_checkOut"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue_button"
                android:text="@string/checkout"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two_board_btn_cart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue_button"
                android:text="@string/add_to_cart"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove @style from Both the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by add this to the second button:

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

How much long your Button name. you have already used the match parent. So, only you can do to reduce the textSize of Button. That's All.

Comment: you should share the screenshot, so every one can understand easily. and suggest you correct answer.